# Underlying topological space of $X_y = X \times_Y Spec \hspace{0.5mm} k(y)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and let $y \in Y$ be a point, $k(y)$ the residue field of $y$, $Spec \hspace{0.5mm} k(y) \to Y$ the natural morphism.

Let $X_y = X \times_Y Spec \hspace{0.5mm} k(y)$ be the *fibre of a morphism $f$ over the point $y$*.

I am slightly unsure what $sp(X_y)$ is. Since $k(y)$ is a field, $Spek \hspace{0.5mm} k(y) = (0)$, i.e. is composed of only the zero ideal.

Would the underlying topological space of $X_y$ be $(x, (0))$ where $x \in X$?

I think I might be missing something because $(x, (0))$ is homeomorphic to $X$, which I doubt is the case.

Comment: $Speck(y)$ is the reason `operatorname` exists :) `\operatorname{Spec}k(y)` produces $\operatorname{Spec}k(y)$

Comment: Good to know! Thanks.

Comment: It is a very common exercise to show that the natural morphism $X_y \to X$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, which is exactly $f^{-1}(y)$ (which is not necessarily closed or open). So as a topological space this is a very natural thing.

Comment: A counter-example to the guess that you doubt anyway: $X=Y$ and $f$ the identity.

Comment: @Hoot By the natural morphism are you referring to the projection $p: X_y \to X$?

Comment: Yes. I don't see any other!